# I suggest eliminating tag "fingerstyle-violin"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

This has bugged me for a while, but I don't have the privilege to edit tags. There's a tag called [fingerstyle-violin](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerstyle-violin). I would argue that there shouldn't be.

"Fingerstyle" is a [familiar term for guitarists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerstyle_guitar), a technique and by extension a genre: plucking with the fingers of the right hand instead of using a pick. There is a [fingerstyle-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerstyle-guitar) tag here with 144 uses, and [fingerstyle-bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerstyle-bass). (I'm not sure whether the latter is also a bit of a dubious usage, since I feel like using pick on bass is less common than fingers?)

Anyway, "fingerstyle" just isn't in the common vocabulary of violin-family instruments. We don't normally use a pick, and using the fingers directly on the strings is usually referred to as *pizzicato* or simply "plucking" for a more vernacular option. (Side note: There is a [pizzicato](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pizzicato) tag; its 17 questions are all about bowed-string instruments. There's also [plucking](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plucking), though it has no usage guidance and contains one violin question and two for guitar and one for bass. Perhaps "plucking" should become a synonym of pizzicato? Maybe vice versa?)

Anyway back to "fingerstyle-violin": all the questions currently tagged with it are about left-hand fingering choices, and the usage guidance actually says "Use this tag when you have questions about **fingering** on the violin." And yes, there's a [fingering](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingering) tag. I would imagine the best action would be to tag all the "fingerstyle-violin" questions with the combo "fingering" and "violin" and then delete the tag.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace this is not a burn request. Burn requests prevent the tag from ever being made again and are a much bigger process.

Comment: @Dom Hm... should it be? I'm sure it would be easy enough to keep an eye out and re-migrate if it were to be created again. Maybe burn requests are to fight abuse?

Comment: Burning is a bigger process that we're still waiting on for some tags (I realized one needed one was missing the explicit tag request).  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191 for a general rule of thumb. As I see it, this is a minimally used tag unlikely to come up again if removed so the full burn may be overkill.

Comment: Also this meta post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242624/why-dont-we-block-all-tags-that-we-remove

Comment: @Dom Oh, okay.  Well, now I'm more confused. Those posts suggests that *burninating* and *blocking* are different.  This question should at least have [retagging], right?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace retagging is fine. I'd like to carve out when each tag should be used as every [rettaging] question will have [tag] when it should be used should be fleshed out. The [burninate-request] will be put into a staff queue so we got to be careful with it.

Comment: I agree that it's actually a non-term where violin is concerned. A pointless tag. Just get shut of it. Other terms are available, and far more apposite.

Answer (score 3):

This proposal has clear support and there's really not a high volume of questions so over the next few days we should edit out [fingerstyle-violin](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerstyle-violin) and replaced with [fingering](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingering).

For the question of the tag [plucking](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plucking) we should ask a new question as it's a little less clear on the path of that.